# Instability in Lattice Boltzmann Solver

Tags: fluid-dynamics, lattice-boltzmann-methods

I [wrote](https://github.com/taktoa/chemsim/blob/master/src/lbm.rs) a Lattice Boltzmann Solver in Rust a little while back using both the BGK approximation and the TRT (two relaxation time) method on the D2Q9 lattice. In both cases I run into major stability problems even in simple examples. Here is a video of the output from the simulation of a left-to-right flow with a cylindrical obstruction (using the bounce-back method): [link](https://gfycat.com/idlebowedindochinesetiger). This video shows momentum density using lightness as magnitude and color as direction. I can't remember if it was generated with BGK or TRT but I experienced similar failures with both collision operators. I'm using convolution with a `[[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]` stencil to implement the streaming step. I tried following the steps described in *The Lattice Boltzmann Method: Principles and Practice* for getting stability in BGK and TRT simulations, but haven't had any luck. Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: What flow regime are you running, I know that LBM has problems with stability in high speed flows and requires large stencils in those cases